# Memory issue when calculating matrix inverse by C++

Tags: c++, matrix, memory, inversion

I am now using some c++ code to compute matrix inverse and the matrix is stored in a two-dimensional array.

However, I met some possible memory issues that I had no idea how to fix it. Sometimes, I can get good return while sometimes error occurs. Really appreciate if you can give advice.

I got error message "malloc: *** error for object 0x163faaa38: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
".

Also, please see this picture and I use it to indicate which part of the code might go wrong.

[image: possible error code line]

Thank you very much.

```
long double Determinant(long double **a, int n)
{
    int i, j, j1, j2 ;                    // general loop and matrix subscripts
    long double det = 0 ;                   // init determinant
    // pointer to pointers to implement 2d
    // square array
    long double **m;
    if (n == 1) {                 // should not get here
        det = a[0][0] ;
    }

    else if (n == 2)  {                // basic 2X2 sub-matrix determinate
        // definition. When n==2, this ends the
        det = a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[1][0] * a[0][1] ;// the recursion series
    }

    // recursion continues, solve next sub-matrix
    else {                             // solve the next minor by building a
        // sub matrix
        det = 0 ;                      // initialize determinant of sub-matrix

        // for each column in sub-matrix
        for (j1 = 0 ; j1 < n ; j1++) {
            // get space for the pointer list
            m = new long double*[n-1];
            //m = (double **) malloc((n-1)* sizeof(double *)) ;

            for (i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++)
                m[i] = new long double[n-1];
            //     i[0][1][2][3]  first malloc
            //  m -> +  +  +  +   space for 4 pointers
            //       |  |  |  |          j  second malloc
            //       |  |  |  +-> _ _ _ [0] pointers to
            //       |  |  +----> _ _ _ [1] and memory for
            //       |  +-------> _ a _ [2] 4 doubles
            //       +----------> _ _ _ [3]
            //
            //                   a[1][2]
            // build sub-matrix with minor elements excluded
            for (i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
                j2 = 0 ;               // start at first sum-matrix column position
                // loop to copy source matrix less one column
                for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j++) {
                    if (j == j1) continue ; // don't copy the minor column element

                    m[i-1][j2] = a[i][j] ;  // copy source element into new sub-matrix
                    // i-1 because new sub-matrix is one row
                    // (and column) smaller with excluded minors
                    j2++ ;                  // move to next sub-matrix column position
                }
            }

            det += pow(-1.0, 1.0 + j1 + 1.0) * a[0][j1] * Determinant(m, n-1);
            // sum x raised to y power
            // recursively get determinant of next
            // sub-matrix which is now one
            // row & column smaller
            for (i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++) delete m[i];// free the storage allocated to
            // to this minor's set of pointers
            // free the storage for the original
            // pointer to pointer
            delete [] m;
        }

    }

    return(det);
}

// calculate the cofactor of element (row,col)
void GetMinor(long double **src, long double **dest, int row, int col, int order)
{
    // indicate which col and row is being copied to dest
    int colCount=0,rowCount=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < order; i++ )
    {
        if( i != row )
        {
            colCount = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < order; j++ )
            {
                // when j is not the element
                if( j != col )
                {
                    dest[rowCount][colCount] = src[i][j];
                    colCount++;
                }
            }
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}

// Calculate the determinant recursively.
long double CalcDeterminant(long double **mat, int order)
{
    // order must be >= 0
    // stop the recursion when matrix is a single element
    if( order == 1 )
        return mat[0][0];

    // the determinant value
    long double det = 0;

    // allocate the cofactor matrix
    long double **minor;
    minor = new long double*[order-1];
    for(int i=0;i<order-1;i++)
        minor[i] = new long double[order-1];

    for(int i = 0; i < order; i++)
    {
        // get minor of element (0,i)
        GetMinor(mat, minor, 0, i, order);
        // the recusion is here!

        det += (i%2==1?-1.0:1.0) * mat[0][i] * CalcDeterminant(minor,order-1);
        //det += pow( -1.0, i ) * mat[0][i] * CalcDeterminant( minor,order-1 );
    }

    // release memory
    for(int i=0;i<order-1;i++)
        delete [] minor[i];
    delete [] minor;

    return det;
}


// matrix inversioon

void MatrixInversion(long double **InputM, int order, long double **InvM)
{
    // get the determinant of a
    long double det = 1.0/CalcDeterminant(InputM, order);

    // memory allocation
    long double *temp = new long double[(order-1)*(order-1)];
    long double **minor = new long double*[order-1];
    for(int i=0;i<order-1;i++)
        minor[i] = temp+(i*(order-1));

    for(int j=0;j<order;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<order;i++)
        {
            // get the co-factor (matrix) of A(j,i)
            GetMinor(InputM,minor,j,i,order);
            InvM[i][j] = det*CalcDeterminant(minor,order-1);
            if((i+j)%2 == 1)
                InvM[i][j] = -InvM[i][j];
        }
    }

    // release memory
    //delete [] minor[0];
    delete [] temp;
    for(int i=0; i<order-1; i++)
        delete [] minor[i];
    delete [] minor;
}
```

Comment: Recommend running your program through a memory usage checker like AddressSanitizer or valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of this code in the `MatrixInversion` function;

```
delete [] temp;
for(int i=0; i<order-1; i++)
    delete [] minor[i];
delete [] minor;
```

The variables `temp` and `minor` were defined as follows:

```
long double *temp = new long double[(order-1)*(order-1)];
long double **minor = new long double*[order-1];
for(int i=0;i<order-1;i++)
     minor[i] = temp+(i*(order-1));
```

Each row in the `minor` matrix does not have new memory allocated to it; rather, it's just a pointer into the `temp` array. So what happens is you try to delete memory that wasn't allocated with `new`.

You should remove the `for` loop deleting the elements of `minor`. That memory will be freed when you `delete [] temp;`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I changed that part but still had the same issue.

Comment: @ZZ32 one thing I recommend is setting pointers to `nullptr` after they've been `delete`d. That way you'll get a segfault immediately when you try to use it. That usually makes debugging easier.